# How can I get an ordered list of the most called functions in a run of my application in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can I get an ordered (number of calls) list of the most called functions in a run of my application?

**e.g:**

1.`<NSObject:0x000000:init>`

2.`<MyObject:0x000000:setPosition>`

**etc**

Is this possible using build in xCode tools?

If not, is it possible to override objc_msgSend and implement this functionality?

I am aware of the possible overhead of this however it would only be used in testing.

Thank You,

Nonono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Instruments, particularly the Time Profiler instrument:

[image]

(You can see more fields like Total Samples instead of just time-based fields, if you right-click on the table header.)